# Impersonating phishing incident

Tags: phishing, email-spoofing

An email has been circulated with the username of our organization, with some internal users and also to the customers. Observed that IP 40.92.46.74, which is Microsoft one. We have been using our organizational email-signature for all our users. that email-signature is being used in this impersonation incident circulating the spoof email with internal users and customers. we are using Mimecast secure email gateway. please help us how to efficiently prevent similar emails?